# Taking screenshots during installation of Ubuntu

Tags: screenshot

I am going to install Ubuntu Server. On numerous websites, I have observed screenshots of the install process. If I would like to take a screenshot of the install process, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try installing an screen capture app for console before beginning the install process like the gnome-screenshot tool. I don't recommend installing this because you will need some gnome dependencies i think but you can search for another app and install it from ubuntu-server media. You can install it using another tty and taking screenshots to check if it works before the installation process begins

Comment: you can take screenshots from the console with ImageMagick http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-ubuntu-linux

Comment: -1 for "that's not going to work". Ubuntu server has a non-graphical install interface, different from the live-cd install that desktop Ubuntu has; *gnome*-screenshot works for making screenshots of graphical ("X server") windows. Same thing with ImageMagick. See e.g. this for what such screenshots look like: http://www.basicconfig.com/ubuntu_installation_screenshots

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way would be to do the install within a virtualbox guest installation.

You could snapshot the virtualbox guest window using either standard gnome-screenshot or better still, with Shutter.

Comment: VB would indeed be the easiest method.

Comment: Agreed , Vbox / KVM , some forum of virutalization is much easier as you can continue to work on the host (assuming you are using the screenshots for some forum of documentation or posting screenshots on the web).